# How to check if address written in correct structure PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How do I check if an adress is written in a correct structure.

Let's say I got a table like this..

```
ID - Name - Email - Adress

1 - John - john@example.com - Exampleroad 10, 123 45 City

2 - John2 - john2@example.com - Exampleroad 12-14, 123 45 City

3 - John3 - john3@example.com - Exampleroad 106, 123 45 City

4 - John4 - john4@example.com - Exampleroad 33

5 - John5 - john4@example.com - Exampleroad 16 123 45 City

6 - John6 - john4@example.com - Exampleroad, 123 45 City


ID 4,5 and 6 are incorrect,
```

Is their anyway to check this?

```
ID 4: MISSING, ZIP AND CITY

ID 5: MISSING COMMA

ID 6: MISSING ROADNUMBER
```

Comment: Dont check post factum,just dont let people register without filling all the fields.Validate input

Comment: If you are saving `Address` as `text` then, no need to check for formats.Otherwise change your table structure and add columns `city` & `zip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multipart fields should always be separated into their own fields as a best practice. This is so you can check each part of the address to be correct, but also be able to use each part of the data individually if needed.

You should split out your address into multiple columns.

AddressLine1
AddressLine2
Town
State
Postcode

Can obviously also add 3rd line of address and country if needed.